# what is network.target and do I need it?

Tags: networking

I am using Ubuntu + wpa_supplicant + dhcpcd ..

**systemctl | grep network** returns network.target

network.target was not enabled in the beginning but somehow it showed up..

what is network.target ?
which package does network.target belong to ?
Do I need it ? should I stop/disable it ?

Answer (score 1):

network.target is a systemd thing. Since you use the network, you need it. It's a normal part of everybody's startup.

The target itself is reached (achieved) when you have network connectivity.

All the jobs within that target are run with the goal of bringing up the network.

Some other startup jobs cannot be started until the network is up (like mounting network drives or synchronizing email). They depend upon that target to avoid starting too early and failing.

Comment: "Since you use the network" by this you mean my network ?(wpa_supplicant + dhcpcd) ?

Comment: Yes, wireless is included in "the network"